# Make wpcap.dll "optional"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, dll, winpcap

I'm writing a program that make use of WinPcap to access network traffic.

My question is, supposed I run the program on a machine where there is no WinPcap installed (i.e. no wpcap.dll), the executable once started will try to load the DLL dependencies and crash when it find out that there is no wpcap.dll.

In such case I'd like to fallback to WinSock without the program to crash. Is this even possible?

The only solution I can immagine, is to remove the winpcap dependency from the linker and manually try to load the wpcap DLL via the LoadLibrary call. 
Can I in some way prevent the crash during the app initialization? (i.e. catch the "DLL not found" and continue the execution using the WinSocks alternative)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options are:

1. Switch from load-time to run-time linking as proposed in the question. That means using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to load the DLL and bind to its functions.
2. Switch to [delay loading the DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan, option 2 is the one I was looking for!